# Multidrop Bus addressing

Tags: bus, multidrop-bus

Currently I am reading the MDB_interface_specification( (https://namanow.org/wp-content/uploads/Multi-Drop-Bus-and-Internal-Communication-Protocol.pdf) Version 4. 3(July 2019). In Kapitel 2.3 page 34 they are talking about the Peripheral Address and I don't undrstand how the Address scheme has been built . One prototy of the address scheme look like this: 00101xxxB ( **this can be 28H for example** ). They upper five bits are used for addressing and the lower 3 bit are the command. If i considered this statement wih my **example** then the address ist 5 and the Command is 0. I am a little bit confuse can someone please explain me that?

Answer (score 0):

OK. First, read this:
[image: this is from MDB datasheet]

Then, we have value 0x00 as command to Energy Management System (huh, i never saw this kind of MBD device in the wild). MDB datasheet doesn't contain any references to this device yet, but seems it's just POLL command, device must respond to POLL with last status changes (if any) or just ACK with x100 - it's not mistake, it's 0x00 with 9th bit set. Don't read this datasheet unless you want to lose your mind. I am already read this awesome shit and put it (mostly) to hardware implementation see [github repo with complete solution](https://github.com/perdidor/Arduino-MDB-UART)

Cheers.